# Is there a way to "downgrade" (revert) an HTC Desire HD to stock Froyo from Gingerbread?

Tags: htc-desire-hd, downgrade

I don't have any backups or whatever. My phone isn't rooted. It updated to Gingerbread 2.3.3 OTA a couple of days ago, and I hate almost every change that it introduced.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no answer to the question, but am curious to know what are the changes you so dislike? I have an HTC Incredible S and will probably be upgrading soon.

Comment: It's minor, but really annoying changes in interface: 1. Text size in browser is different: normal is smaller, large is too large. 2. Browser skin doesn't follow Sense skin, looks awful. 3. Useless tabs in the slide-down notification area. 4. Uglier widgets, notification icons (personal taste of course). The saddest part is, there are no fundamental changes. I'm using Swype, so the "improved keyboard" doesn't matter to me, and I doubt I'll need NFC. Gingerbread doesn't offer any other improvements AFAIK. Oh, and while typing this, I discovered manual caret positioning is flawed.

Comment: Update: caret positioning seems to be an issue only with stackexchange. I guess it's how the character counters work and isn't a problem introduced by Gingerbread. But the original point still stands.

Answer (score 1):

Stock Froyo, I assume you mean Froyo with HTC Sense on top of it.

You would have to root your phone and then load a Froyo ROM.

[How to Root HTC Desire](http://android.modaco.com/topic/307365-14jun-r6-riskfreeroot-htc-desire-rooting-guide-now-with-hboot-080-and-os-to-121-support/)

See here for instructions to install custom rom: [Modaco Froyo with Sense](http://android.modaco.com/topic/317191-07mar-fr11-with-sense-modaco-custom-rom-for-htc-desire-with-online-kitchen-22-froyo/)